# Problem about Hasse diagrams

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, lattice-orders

Can someone help me to solve this problem.

Are [these Hasse diagrams](http://s8.postimage.org/3x2bwdjtx/ddd.png) lattices?

[image]

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: I know lattice:"A partially ordered set in which every pair of elements has both a least upper bound and a
greatest lower bound is called a lattice"and i think first diagram is lattice.

Comment: Okay $-$ and you're right. What about the others?

Comment: But I need a tutorial or complete explain about lattice.

Comment: You've already said everything you need to know. Do you know what a least upper bound/greatest lower bound is? And how Hasse diagrams work?

Comment: yes,I guess second diagram is lattice .

Comment: Correct! And the third? Don't worry, I'll write a more comprehensive response soon $-$ but it's worth properly thinking about them first.

Comment: I guess the third diagram is lattice(with doubt)

Comment: Correct again! I'll write an answer now.

Answer (score 4):

2nd one is not a lattice. (b,c) have three Upper Bounds none of which is the least upper bound. The other two are lattices.

Answer (score 1):

(Following on the comments.) They're all latices. When you have a Hasse diagram, it's fairly easy to find greatest lower bounds and least upper bounds.

For instance, given $x,y$, if $x \le y$ then $x \vee y = y$ and $x \wedge y = x$. This is easy to spot because you can connect $x$ to $y$ by a path that moves in just one direction. In your first diagram, for example, you know that $a \le e$ because there's an upwards-directed path $a \to b \to e$.

Sometimes we don't have $x \le y$ or $y \le x$, e.g. $f$ and $g$ in your second diagram. To get from $f$ to $g$ you have to move up and down again, or down and up again, so they're not comparable. But that's still not a problem: just by looking at the diagram you can see that $f \vee g = h$ and $f \wedge g = b$.

Comment: Thanks.Can you give me a Hasse diagram that is not lattice?

Comment: Sure: $\vee$ is one $\wedge$ is another, and $\ \cdot\ \cdot\ $ is another.

Comment: What is "\vee ", " \wedge", "\ \cdot\ \cdot\ "?

Comment: Ah, the fact that you're writing that makes me think the MathJax rendering isn't working. "\vee" is meant to look like V, "\wedge" like Λ and "\ \cdot\ \cdot\ " like · ·

Comment: ...it was my way of trying to draw Hasse diagrams.

Comment: The second one isn't a lattice though.